# What makes docker secure?

Tags: docker

I am interested in understanding what makes docker containers secure.

Is it because one container is separated from another and processes do not have access to each other (basically, isolation)?

Or is it the way that a process gets running? (so different than just running a binary code?)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This deserves an answer longer than suitable for Stack Overflow :-)

Some interesting reads would be:

- this [blog post about Docker and LXC containers security](http://blog.docker.io/2013/08/containers-docker-how-secure-are-they/), from august 2013, but still relevant;
- this [presentation about LXC and security](http://www.slideshare.net/jpetazzo/linux-containers-lxc-docker-and-security), from january 2014, more recent but also more terse since it's just a presentation.

TL,DR: processes are isolated, but you also have to take specific steps to lock down some features, otherwise processes can break out of containers. Depending on what you want to run, those steps will be very different.

Comment: thanks for your answer and the links. can you please tell (or give additional links) to understand better what "lock down some features" are? thanks!

Comment: There are many steps, listed in the links :-) e.g. dropping root privileges, using GRSEC (or a security module)...